# Creating SMPP server

Tags: php, ruby, sms, sms-gateway, smpp

I have SMS API that supports JSON AND XML via HTTP protocal, what it does it it receives SMS request from clients in either JSON or XML format and forward it to MNO using [Kannel SMS Gateway](http://www.kannel.org/). Now I have the client whose requirement is that he want to connect to us via SMPP protocol. My question is how do I create SMPP server so that other client could connect to my application using SMPP? Any resources to get me started will much be appreciated.

The process is like this.

1. Receive request from the client via SMPP
2. Validate client information
3. Forward the message to the MNO
4. Send status response to the client.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261906/creating-a-smpp-server-using-http-api/54002274#54002274 to be acquainted to design considerations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I managed to create SMPP server using [Shorty Nodejs SMPP client and server](https://github.com/Roave/shorty)

Comment: how did you handle multiple user login details?

Comment: Hi guys, please how do you run the application.?

Answer (score 1):

WELL to get you started with some ground too information refer this

[LINKS which will help](http://www.activexperts.com/sms-component/smpp-specifications/introduction/)

[THE HOW TO U were asking for](http://www.activexperts.com/sms-component/howto/smpp-send/php/)

Comment: thanks for the links. Correct me if I'm wrong the information you sent is all about how to communicate with SMSC via SMPP something that kannel does it really well, what I'm looking for is how do do I have my own SMPP server where other client would be able to connect to my application, instead of using HTTP they would use SMPP

Comment: I m not sure but , you need to contact your hosting provider for this they will host a SMPP server and provide you with suitable API's which you can later on handle with some scripts.

Comment: I will host myself. We have our own servers. @REX